# Why can't a variable be a stable identifier?

Tags: scala

The following

```
def mMatch(s: String) = {
    var target: String = "a"
    s match {
        case `target` => println("It was " + target)
        case _ => println("It was something else")
    }
}
```

does not compile:

> error: stable identifier required, but target found.
>                  case `target` => println("It was " + target)

Why does Scala require a `val` not a `var`.  I guess "Because" would be an acceptable answer but I have the feeling there is a deeper reason I am missing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suspect that it's to enable table-switching optimizations for those cases where it is possible (without piles of checking to see whether it's valid).  For example, with the code

```
class Sw {
  def m(i: Int) = {
    val a = 3
    val b = 2
    val c = 1
    i match {
      case `a` => 0
      case `b` => -1
      case `c` => 4
      case _ => 2
    }
  }
}
```

you get the bytecode

```
public int m(int);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iconst_2
   3:   istore_3
   4:   iconst_1
   5:   istore  4
   7:   iload_1
   8:   istore  5
   10:  iload   5
   12:  tableswitch{ //1 to 3
        1: 48;
        2: 44;
        3: 52;
        default: 40 }
   40:  iconst_2
   41:  goto    53
   44:  iconst_m1
   45:  goto    53
   48:  iconst_4
   49:  goto    53
   52:  iconst_0
   53:  ireturn
```

which would be much more complicated to do if you used vars (you'd have to detect whether they had changed to know whether that table expression was still valid).

Comment: This is incorrect. Pattern matching does not necessarily use switches. In fact, there is the [`@switch`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.annotation.switch) annotation if you want to ensure that a tableswitch or lookupswitch is used.

Comment: @PaulDraper - I think you're reading something in there that I didn't say. If you want to always have the _option_ of using Feature X, you need to _always_ have the prerequisites met.  I never said that switches were always used!

Comment: @RexKerr, I may have misread. But in any case, with or without stable identifiers, switches are sometimes used and sometimes not. (Specifically, without stable identifiers, they would not be used.) I can see why unstable identifiers can't easily work with *switches*, not why unstable identifiers can't easily work with *pattern matching*.

Comment: @PaulDraper - My point was that I suspected that it's easier that way: code analysis is simpler if identifiers are stable, and you need code analysis to tell that the tableswitch is possible.  It's enabling, not essential.

Answer (score 16):

There's nothing to stop you just turning your var into a val before using it in the match:

```
def mMatch(s: String) = {
    var target: String = "a"
    val x = target
    s match {
        case `x` => println("It was " + target)
        case _ => println("It was something else")
    }
}
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: Exactly.  If *I* can do it, why can't the compiler do it?

Comment: To make you aware of what you're doing.

Answer (score 10):

My guess is stable identifiers are required as a simplification to avoid situations where the variable changes inside the pattern matching itself. This would require clarification in the spec, and disrupt optimizations as Rex Kerr mentions.

```
var x: String = "a"
"b" match {
  case `x` if { x = "b"; true } => println("success")
}
```

*Edit.* But this explanation is not completely satisfactory, because the stable identifier could refer to a mutable object,

```
val x = collection.mutable.Seq(2)
def f(y: Seq[Int]) {
    y match {
      case `x` if { x(0) = 3; true } => println("success")
    }
}
f(Seq(2)) // success
f(Seq(2)) // failure
```

Note that a stable identifier is not necessarily known statically. For example, the following is fine,

```
def f(x: Int) {
  1 match { case `x` => println("hi") }
}
```