# Why val is stable identifier and def is not?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Fields (`val`s) of class instances could be used while pattern matching:

```
class A {
  val foo = 37
  def bar = 42
}

def patmat1(a: A, x: Int) {
  x match {
    case a.foo => println("a.foo")
    case _     => println("not a.foo")
  }
}

patmat1(new A, 37) // => a.foo
patmat1(new A, 42) // => not a.foo
```

And I wonder why `def` cannot be used analogously?

```
def patmat2(a: A, x: Int) {
  x match {
    case a.bar => println("a.bar")
    //     ^ error: stable identifier required, but a.bar found.
    case _     => println("not a.bar")
  }
}
```

I thought that `val` and `def` are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't a variable be a stable identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083502/why-cant-a-variable-be-a-stable-identifier)

Comment: Well, val is a constant and def is a function definition. It could work, but treating nullary function definitions as constants is maybe not a good idea... Or worth the effort.

Comment: @marius No I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @BoldizsárNémeth the answer to this question will be exactly the same. So why is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @MariusDanila You mean that result of `def` may change while pattern matching?

Comment: Potentially it can - why not?

Comment: @VladimirParfinenko It might certainly do. Your `def` might use a `var` in its implementation so the argument is the same

Comment: @marius You are right, but for a new student of scala it might not be so trivial.

Comment: And for further investigation: implementation of custom `unapply` may also depend on state of some global `var`. I think that `def` is not worse than `unapply`.

Answer (score 2):

Well as per [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf), your second case is not a valid pattern. `val foo` works because it is a Stable Identifier Pattern `§ 8.1.5` which basically means that it checks if `x == a.foo`.

Your second case is simply not any valid pattern (as `a.bar` is not a identifier but a declaration) hence the error.

One idiomatic way would be:

```
def patmat1(a: A, x: Int) {
  x match {
    case i if a.bar == x => println("a.foo")
    case _     => println("not a.foo")
  }
}
```

Comment: _A stable identiﬁer is a path which ends in an identiﬁer._ And why `a.bar` is not a stable identifier? I've read `§ 8.1.5` and still do not understand why `a.bar` is prohibited.

Comment: `a.bar` is not an identifier but a declaration

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first part of the left-half of a case statement is to destructure an object or match it to a constant value. So, for example:

```
val animal: Animal = Dog("butch",4)

animal match {
  case _: Dog => println("bow-wow")
  case _: Cat => println("meow")
}
```

If you want to compare to a constant, you can do that in the main part of the case statement:

```
secretConstant match {
  case Math.PI => println("I'm a PI")
  case Math.E  +> println("I'm an E")
  case _ => println("I don't know what I am")
}
```

But if you want to compare against a calculated value, then you need to include it within the `if` portion of a case statement:

```
tomsWeddingDate match {
  case date: LocalDate if date < LocalDate.now() => println("phew, I still have time to buy a gift.")
  case _ => println("Oops, I guess I need to send a belated card")
}
```