# Why can't I pattern match on Stream.empty in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

The code below doesn't compile if I uncomment the line indicated. The compiler complains: "stable identifier required".

```
val Empty = Stream.empty    
val a = Stream.range(0, 5)
a match {
  // case Stream.empty => println("nope") <-- does not work
  case Empty => println("compiles") <-- works
  case _ => println("ok")
}
```

If I assign `Stream.empty` to value `Empty` first, it works, but it feels strange that you can't pattern match on such a fundamental value without such a hack.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't pattern match on `Stream.empty` because it is a **method** (in object `Stream`) that always returns the empty stream (but the compiler doesn't know that).

Instead of assigning `val empty = Stream.empty`, you can match on `Stream.Empty`, which is an `Object` :

```
scala> a match {
           case Stream.Empty => println("done")
           case h #:: tl => println(h)
       }
```

Comment: Confirmed it works for Scala 2.12, at least. Things may be different starting from 2.13.

Answer (score 6):

You can't "pattern match" on a **variable that is not a constant**.
`Stream.empty` is not a "stable" identifier since it represents some method:

```
/** The empty stream */
  override def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty
```

that could potentially return any value at any time.
Compiler isn't aware that its returned value is always `Empty`, so it detects it as a potential changing **variable**.
Too deep for it to detect it.

However, when you assign the method's retult to a `val` (being a stable identifier since immutable), your code is able to process to pattern matching using it.

You might read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083725/985949), evoking an hypothesis explaining why pattern matching expects a stable identifier.