# Finding the index of an element in a list scala

Tags: list, scala

How do I find the index of an element in a Scala list.

```
val ls = List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb")
```

I need to get 3 if I ask for the index of "little"

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
scala> List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb").indexOf("little")
res0: Int = 3
```

You might try reading the [scaladoc for List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) next time. ;)

Comment: List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "little").indexOf("little") will always return 3

Answer (score 53):

If you want to search by a predicate, use `.indexWhere(f)`:

```
val ls = List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb","a")
ls.indexWhere(_.startsWith("l"))
```

This returns 3, since "little" is the first word beginning with letter l.

Answer (score 40):

If you want list of all indices containing "a", then:

```
val ls = List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb","a")
scala> ls.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == "a").map(_._2)
res13: List[Int] = List(2, 5)
```

Comment: Interesting! I think this is what _collect_ is for though: `ls.zipWithIndex.collect { case ("a",i) => i }`

Comment: Is there a way to use `.collect` with a variable ? Like `ls.zipWithIndex.collect { case (someVariableIWantToMatch,i) => i }` ?

Comment: Nevermind, that's about [Stable identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables)