# Function returns the wrong value only when size of array input is 1

Tags: scala, loops, return, pattern-matching

I have a function I wrote in Scala which iterates through an array of `Option`s. I wish to return the first index for which the option is not `None`. My code works alright for all arrays of length greater than 1. It doesn't, however, work for arrays of size 1.

This is my existing code

```
def firstSome(): Int = {
    for (i <- 0 until this.arr.length - 1) {
        this.arr(i) match {
            case Some(_) => {
                println("Returns")
                return i
            }
            case None => // do nothing
        }
    }
    println("Oops")
    return -1
}
```

For some reason, both `Returns` and `Oops` are printed out. I'd thought that the function will return `i` after going to the `Some` case, but somehow it continues despite the return statement.

I've also printed out `this.arr` and confirmed that element inside the array is not `None`.

Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: on a sidenote, you should never use return in Scala for the following reasons: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0 until x` is the range from 0 to x - 1. So there is an off by one error in your `for`, it should be correctly:

```
    for (i <- 0 until this.arr.length) {
       ...
    }
```

As the use of return in Scala is highly [discouraged](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html), I'd like to point out the `find` method to you, which does exactly what you are trying to implement here.

Comment: Is there any way to make `find` return a default value when the element is not found then?

Comment: yes: this.arr.find(_.isDefined).getOrElse(defaultValue)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to writing a custom loop would be to use [indexWhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392134/5205022) method like so

```
arr.indexWhere { 
  case Some(_) => true
  case None => false
}
```

which would also work out-of-the-box for array of length 1.

Comment: `{ case Some(_) => true ; case None => false }` is the same as `(_.nonEmpty)`.