# Pattern matching on non-literal values

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I feel like this is a silly question, but I'll ask anyway... I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def func(x: Int, y: Int) = {
  val value: Int = 0 //from config
  (x, y) match {
    case (value, value) => "foo"
    case _ => "bar"
  }
}
```

But both the repl and intelliJ shower me with warnings. (e.g. "patterns after a variable pattern cannot match"; "suspicious shadowing by a variable pattern"; etc.). Is there a correct way to match on non-literal values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does pattern matching in Scala not work with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables)

Comment: @Clément Man I wrote this 10 years ago i have no idea.

Comment: yeah, this weird comment phrasing is the auto-comment that SO posts when you flag a duplicate.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Clément ahh gotcha. Haha thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes! There are two ways to get what you want. The first is to capitalize the names of the variables you wish to match against:

```
def func(x: Int, y: Int) = {
  val Value: Int = 0 // from config
  (x, y) match {
    case (Value, Value) => "foo"
    case _ => "bar"
  }
}
```

If you don't want to go that route (because it's not idiomatic to capitalize variable names, etc.), you can backtick them in the match:

```
def func(x: Int, y: Int) = {
  val value: Int = 0 // from config
  (x, y) match {
    case (`value`, `value`) => "foo"
    case _ => "bar"
  }
}
```

I'd suggest using backticks in most situations.

Comment: it might be worth adding that the reason is that pattern matching requires a _stable identifier pattern_, which you can obtain using literals, backticks or capitalized names.

Comment: I love it when Travis Brown goes downscale. Is this the only TB answer without a type param or a macro in it?

Comment: @som-snytt: I like to kick back on Sundays.