# convert String to Option[String]

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to scala programming and am facing difficulty to convert from String to Option[String]. I am not sure if the approach I am following is correct or not. Here is the code:

```
EmpInfo.scala:

package model
case class EmpInfo(empType: Option[String]) extends Named {
  override def name: String = clientName
}

EmpReconciliator.scala

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.mvc.AnyContent
import model.EmpInfo

trait EmpReconciliator[A] extends BaseController[A] {

  val oldName  = "abc"
  val newName = "xyz"
  def reconcileGeneric(genericResource: A) = {
    (genericResource match {         
      case empInfo : EmpInfo => reconcileEmpInfo(empInfo)
      case other@_ => other
    }).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def reconcileEmpInfo(empInfo: EmpInfo) = {
    empInfo.empTypeType match {
      case Some(oldName) => empInfo.copy(empType = Some(newName))
      case _ => empInfo
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I need to replace all instances of `oldName` with `newName`.
But instead, I am getting `"1"` in the response. I cannot change type of `empType: Option[String]` to `String` (need it that way).
I know it's a very minor change needed but cannot place what.
Please help.

Comment: For what input do you get `"1"` as a response?

Comment: `empInfo.copy(empType = Some(newName))` never use Some in this case. Use 
`empInfo.copy(empType = Option(newName))`

but and answer is
instead of `case Some(oldName) => empInfo.copy(empType = Some(newName))`
use `case Some(oldName) => empInfo.empType.map(newName)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. But if you want to use `oldName` as a pattern, you have to capitalize it.

```
val OldName  = "abc"
val newName = "xyz"

empInfo.empType match {
  case Some(OldName) => empInfo.copy(empType = Some(newName))
  case _ => empInfo
}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem you're having, please state your problem more clearly and precisely.

Comment: see, also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables

Comment: Type of `Some("a string")`: `Option[String]`. Get `String` Value of a `Option[String]` type: `str.get`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add toString()
               here 
          case Some(oldName) => empInfo.copy(empType = 
          Some(newName)).toString()
          case _ => empInfo

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to achieve but maybe this helps you:

```
def reconcileEmpInfo(empInfo: EmpInfo) : EmpInfo  = {
    EmpInfo(Option(newName))
}
```

think that you should not update EmpInfo. if you need newName inside just create a new one and use the new one.
The garbage collector will clean the old one.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, the problem that you are facing is to convert a `String` type to `Option[String]` type.

Then try wrapping it like this: `Option(<variablename>)`, as in `Option(newvalue)` in your example.